# Proving $\hat K(\omega \wedge k) = (-1)^{pq} \omega \wedge \hat K(\eta)$

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

I am currently trying to make Exercise 22 of these [lecture notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_AK0HGxgYXJas46SWFxTmbNR0eCCTH2/view). I am stuck on what I believe to be maybe something trivial, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to tackle this question.
I'll add the relevant information below.

### The Question

For this question, we first need to define the "wedge" product between $K \in \Omega^p(M, \mathrm{End}(E)$ and $\eta \in \Omega^q(M, E)$. We define
$$
(K \wedge \eta)(X_1, \ldots, X_{p + q}) = \sum_{\sigma} \mathrm{sign}(\sigma) K(X_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, X_{\sigma(p)})\left( \eta(X_{\sigma(p+1)}, \ldots, \eta(X_{\sigma(p+q)}) \right),
$$
where the sum is over all $(p,q)$-shuffles $\sigma$, i.e. all permuations $\sigma$ with $\sigma(1) < \ldots < \sigma(p)$ and $\sigma(p + 1) < \ldots < \sigma(p + q)$.

Any such $K$ induces a linear map
$$
\hat K \colon \Omega^\bullet(M,E) \to \Omega^{\bullet + q}(M,E): \eta \mapsto K \wedge \eta.
$$

> **Exercise 22.** Show that $\hat K$ is an endomorphism of the graded (left) $\Omega(M)$-module $\Omega(M,E)$, i.e. according to the graded sign rule:
> $$
> \hat K(\omega \wedge \eta) = (-1)^{pq} \omega \wedge \hat K(\eta).
> $$

### My strategies, my work and what I find hard

I have tried to write out both sides of this equation, but that ends up in a mess. See my work [here](https://pdfhost.io/edit?doc=75f69d61-1d40-4176-9ca1-d1c4470b269f).
I then tried to take a step back and thought if there was a way to use other properties that were already established. I thought of this:
\begin{align*}
\hat K(\omega \wedge \eta) &= K \wedge (\omega \wedge \eta) \\
&= (K \wedge \omega) \wedge \eta \\
&= (-1)^{pq} (\omega \wedge K) \wedge \eta \\
&= (-1)^{pq} \omega \wedge (K \wedge \eta) \\
&= (-1)^{pq} (\omega) \wedge \hat K(\eta).
\end{align*}

The only thing that is bothering me is the associativity of the "wedge products". Trying to prove that associativity, brings about the same mess as before. Is the right strategy or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You mean $\Omega^{\bullet+q}(E)$, I presume.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah oops! I corrected it, I meant $\Omega^{\bullet + q}(M,E)$

Comment: I think in general, if $E_1,E_2,E_3$ are bundles over $M$ and $\cdot$ is a tensorial bilinear map $\Gamma E_1\times \Gamma E_2\to\Gamma E_3$ one can define a wedge product $\Omega(M,E_1)\times\Omega(M,E_2)\to\Omega(M,E_3)$. If $\cdot$ is commutative, then the wedge product is graded commutative. If two such multiplications are associative, then the induced  wedge products are associative. I never really checked this, but i think the proof should be the same as for real valued forms?

Comment: ... by $\cdot$ commutative i really mean that if $*:\Gamma E_2\times\Gamma E_1\to\Gamma E_3$ is the dual multiplikation: $e_1*e_2=e_2\cdot e_1$ then the associated wedge products are graded commutative, as for example used in the third equality of your solution.